# Pyqt5 Why does my image load as a PNG but not a JPG?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qimage

I'm using QPixmap to display an jpg image but it doesn't display. I converted the jpg image into a png and that works but I'd like to know the reason for it.

```
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("information.jpg")
self.infoLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
self.infoLabel.resize(100, 100)
```

Loading as a jpg looks like this

[image]

while a png looks like this

[image]

**EDIT:**

Disclaimer: I manually resized the windows.

After I ran:

```
 print(QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats())
```

The output was:

```
[PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'bmp'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'cur'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'gif'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'icns'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'ico'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'jpeg'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'jpg'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'pbm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'pgm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'png'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'ppm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'svg'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'svgz'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'tga'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'tif'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'tiff'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'wbmp'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'webp'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'xbm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'xpm')]
```

**Edit2:**

Entire program:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 400)

        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        #Label as image code
        self.infoLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("information.jpg")
        self.infoLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.infoLabel.resize(100, 100)
        print(QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()) 
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.infoLabel)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Test"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: whats is your OS?

Comment: My OS is Windows 10

Comment: When you ran it did not generate any error messages in the terminal?

Comment: No errors at all.

Comment: execute this, please: `print(QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats())`

Comment: How have you installed pyqt5?

Comment: execute: `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
print(QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats())`

Comment: See my edit for the output. Yes, I've installed pyqt5.

Comment: I find it strange since you have the support of jpeg: `PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'jpeg')`, you could share the image inside a zip to be able to review it.

Comment: You say you have converted the jpg to png, you could explain that better.

Comment: I converted the jpg to png using https://convertio.co/jpg-png/.

Comment: You could share that .jpg file via drive or similar in zip.

Comment: Since you mentioned I DO have support of JPG, I downloaded a random jpg from google and it displayed fine. information.jpg file must be bad for some reason, even though I got it from the "setIcon()" section from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qmessagebox.htm

Comment: Here it is on google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-3HmoSUfYCkeWZIUWMtd3dNVms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The problem is that image, since I have tried it with other .jpg and it works, but with that image it generates the same error that you have.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: It seems that the problem has been generated by the downloader or the author of the post that uploaded it with an inadequate extension. If you change the .jpg extension to .png it works.

Comment: I will post this response, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the image you downloaded : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/images/information.jpg  has an inadequate extension, it is actually a .png image. This causes Qt, and therefore PyQt, not to be able to recognize it, and therefore does not load it correctly.